# Error: TypeError: 'update' is not a function

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I am using MongoDb Triggers for updating a document after it is inserted. I want to update the `id` field (not `_id`) after it has been inserted. I am using this piece of code:
[image]

```
exports = function(changeEvent) {  

const docId = changeEvent.documentKey._id;
  
 const collection = context.services.get("Cluster0").db("videosDb").collection("videos");
  
  const count = collection.count();
  
  collection.update(
   { _id: docId },
   {
     $set: {
       id: count + 1
     }
   }
);
```

But when I tested it, it returned `Error: TypeError: 'update' is not a function` 
Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can you try `update_one()`?

Comment: Thanks ! But, it returned: `Error: TypeError: 'update_one' is not a function`

Comment: Maybe it is `updateOne`. However it seems that `collection` isn't a collection object since it says `TypeError`

Comment: can you try like once and post error
  `const collection = db.collection('collectionName')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks everyone! 
Finally, I got the answer. This piece of code worked:

```
exports = function (changeEvent) {
if (changeEvent.operationType === "insert") {
  const docName = changeEvent.fullDocument.name;

  const collection = context.services
    .get("Cluster0")
    .db("videosDb")
    .collection("videos");

  collection.count().then((count) => {
    const newCount = count + 1 - 1;
    
    const stringCount = String(newCount);

    collection.updateOne(
      { name: docName },
      {
        $set: {
          id: stringCount,
        },
      }
    );
  });
 }
};
```